# How to access the correct this inside a method of an object

Tags: javascript, this

I have an event handler which calls the `selectContinents()` function:

```
var map = {
    eventHandler: function() {
        events.on('continentsChangedDropdown', (continents) => this.selectContinents(continents));
    },
    selectFeature: function(layer) {
            //selects feature;
    },
    unselectFeature: function(layer) {
            //unselects feature;
    },
    selectContinents: function(continents) {
        geojson.eachLayer(function(layer) {
            var continent = layer.feature.properties.continent;
            if (continents.includes(continent)) {
                this.selectFeature.bind(this, layer);
            }
            else {
                this.unselectFeature.bind(this, layer);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

which in turn calls either `selectFeature()` or `unselectFeature()`.

However this returns

```
map.js:105 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
```

I understand this in this in bind(this) doesn't refer to the map object, but I don't know how to access the map object.

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow function instead. They keep the enclosing scope:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

```
geojson.eachLayer((layer) => {
    var continent = layer.feature.properties.continent;
        if (continents.includes(continent)) {
            this.selectFeature.bind(this, layer);
        }
        else {
            this.unselectFeature.bind(this, layer);
        }
    });
```

Comment: It now doesn't call the select/unselectFeature() methods. There is no error message though.